# How can I upgrade Babylon.js v4.x.x to v.5.x.x?

Tags: babylonjs

I create a project with React.js and Babylon.js. My current version of Babylon.js is now 4.1.0. But I want to change it with version 5.0.0 alpha 63 .. I am new at using babylon. please describe me step by step. Thanks

Answer (score 1):

As of this moment, BabylonJS 5.x is still in beta, so it wont install by default.  Ordinarily, you would install via:

`npm i @babylonjs/core`

which implies "@babylonjs/core@latest" which is officially v4.2.0.  To get v5, use

`npm i @babylonjs/core@preview`

.. which at this moment maps to v5.0.0-beta.4.
Note that if you're also using their loaders, you'll likewise need to upgrade that package:

`npm i @babylonjs/loaders@preview`

Afterwards, your package.json should look *more or less* like:

```
"dependencies": {
    "@babylonjs/core": "^5.0.0-beta.4",
    "@babylonjs/loaders": "^5.0.0-beta.4",
    ...
```

I cant guarantee there are no breaking changes in this upgrade, but I just did the very same from v4.2.0 -> v5.0.0.b4 10 minutes ago, and at a glance all seems well.